# MYSQL syntax error, with date time

Tags: mysql

I am currently converting my api from SQL to MySQL, however one of my queries is failing at this point below.

The query:

```
SELECT u.DATETIME,
       SUM(Value * m.Multiplier) * 1 AS Usage,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.DATETIME)) as Datestamp_epoch 
FROM MeterMaps m
JOIN UsageElectricityDaily u ON m.ChanID = u.ChanID
JOIN SourceChannels c ON c.ChanID = m.ChanID
WHERE m.LocationID = 1
      AND c.QuantityID = 'Usage'
      AND u.DateStamp >= '01/12/2016 00:00:00'
      AND u.DateStamp < '31/12/2016 00:00:00'
      AND m.Utility = 'Electric'
GROUP BY u.Datestamp
```

The error that is thrown is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Usage, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.DATETIME)) ' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the word `usage` is a [keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), therefore it must be enclosed by backticks or change it.

```
SELECT u.DATETIME,
       SUM(Value * m.Multiplier) * 1 AS `Usage`
...
```